# How to change Qt Creator build tool?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

Is there anyway to change the build tool Qt Creator uses? Currently, Qt Creator has defaulted to the `Qt5` version of `qmake`. I would like to use the `Qt4` version of `qmake`, or the `/usr/bin/make/` option. What are the steps needed to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

> Go to Tools->Options->Build&Run

Then select `Qt Versions` tab. You can add `qmake` there by giving path manually

While building project you can select the respective toolchain as well. That can be done from left panel option `project` then select the configured toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project folder in the left sidebar (under the debug button). Then click 'Manage kits' and create a new kit including the Qt4 make path or change the qmake path of your current path for the qt4 one. The QMake is chosen under the tab QtVersions.